# How do I add all items from txt to a listbox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So basically I need a button that will add all text from txt file, that already exists in the folder of bin/debug. I was trying to come up with something but it didn't go that well

```
const string sPath = "save.txt";

        System.IO.StreamReader ReadFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(sPath);
        if (File.Exists(sPath))
        {
            string str = File.ReadAllText(sPath);
            foreach (char item in sPath)             
            { 
                ListBoxOutput.Items.Add(str);

            }             
        }

        ReadFile.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Information loaded");
```

Upd: Thanks for the help, I ended up with this:

```
 const string sPath = "save.txt";

        System.IO.StreamReader ReadFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(sPath);
        if (File.Exists(sPath))
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(sPath);

            foreach (string item in lines)
            {
                ListBoxOutput.Items.Add(item);

            }
        }

        ReadFile.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Information loaded!");
```

Comment: What is your question? `It didn't go well` is not that much information so other people can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
string str = File.ReadAllText(sPath);
foreach (char item in sPath)             
{ 
    ListBoxOutput.Items.Add(str);// there you add all your file content N times where N - count of characters in save file path
}
```

to

```
string[] str = File.ReadAllLines(sPath);
foreach (string item in str)             
{ 
    ListBoxOutput.Items.Add(item);
}
```

it is not to clear what you are trying to achieve, but hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
string str = File.ReadAllText(sPath);
    foreach (char item in sPath)             
    { 
        ListBoxOutput.Items.Add(str);
    }
```

To this

```
IEnumerable<string> str = File.ReadLines(sPath);
foreach (string item in str)             
{ 
    ListBoxOutput.Items.Add(item);
}
```

I think that's what you need. By the way if you have a small file you can use

```
File.ReadAllLines(sPath)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding items one by one to the ListBox, just assign the string array returned by `File.ReadAllLines` to the ListBox' `DataSource` property.

```
ListBoxOutput.DataSource = File.ReadAllLines(sPath);
```

Note: There is no point in opening the `StreamReader`, since you are not using it. The entire code:

```
const string sPath = "save.txt";

if (File.Exists(sPath)) {
    ListBoxOutput.DataSource = File.ReadAllLines(sPath);
    MessageBox.Show("Information loaded");
}  else {
    MessageBox.Show("File doesn't exist.");
}
```

See also: [File.ReadAllLines Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netcore-3.1)